# Помогите решить проблему с записью в другой файл числа в измененном виде

Tags: python

Прочитать файл, который состоит из вещественных чисел порядка `a[1], a[2]..a[n]` и записать из него в другой файл числа порядка `a[1]+a[2n], a[2]+a[2n-1],... a[k]+a[k+1]`

Выходит такая ошибка:

```
[1, 2, 5, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/пппп/Desktop/ff.py", line 18, in <module>
    s=c+a[i+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Не могли бы подсказать, как можно записать в другой файл числа порядка `a[1]+a[2n], a[2]+a[2n-1],... a[k]+a[k+1]`?

Это мой код:

```
import math as m
f=open('qwerty.txt','r')
a=[]
i=0
b=[]
n=0
p=0
for i in f:
    a.append(int(i))
    n=n+1
s=0
c=0
print(a)
i=0
w=open('qwerty2','w')
for i in range(n):
    c=c+a[i]
    s=c+a[i+1]   
    b.append(s)
    w.write(str(s))
    w.write('\t')
print(b)
f.close()
w.close()
```

Comment: А в чём проблема, которую надо помочь решить?

Comment: Ваш код не работает?

Comment: Если последнее число в исходном файле - a[n], то откуда должны браться числа a[n+1], a[2n+1] и т.д.? Приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных...

Comment: Я неправильно написал условие задачи. Поправил. Теперь можете посмотреть. Хоть подсказку можете дать?

Comment: @tima Перечитайте вопрос MaxU

Comment: Приведеная ошибка возникает из-за того, что происходит попытка обращения к несуществующему элементу ``a[i+1]``, тогда как последний элемент в списке ´´а`` это ``a[i]``. Еще: в переменной ``n`` у вас хранится длина списка, поэтому ее можно выкинуть. Длина списка получается функцией ``len(a)``. И второй файл у вас будет без расширения, добавьте там ``.txt``.